# NSPressGestureRecognizer doesn't work in modal ViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a subclass of NSViewController, there is a view in it, which is added a NSPressGestureRecognizer.

If I present the ViewController as show style in StoryboardSegue, NSPressGestureRecognizer works. If I show the ViewController as modal style in StoryboardSegue, NSPressGestureRecognizer doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

```swift
import Cocoa

class VC: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBrown.cgColor
        let longPress = NSPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }

    @objc func longPress(_ sender:Any) {
        print("long")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  What seems to be happening is that the recognizer state never changes from `possible` to `began` in the modal example.

Creating this...

```
class Recognizer: NSPressGestureRecognizer {

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
        self.state = .began
    }

}
```

...and modifying a line of your code to be...

```
    let longPress = Recognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
```

...works at least to the point of printing "long".

Warning: I suggest more investigation since I have no idea whether anything will break as a result of this override.  (But it points out the area that varies between the two cases.)

Comment: What this should probably do is dispatch the state change to happen after the minimum time interval has passed.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a 'working' `Recognizer`, thanks to the inspiration of @phillip-mills.

```
import Cocoa

class VC: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBrown.cgColor
        let longPress = MyPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

        let click = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(click(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(click)

        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }

    @objc func click(_ sender:Any) {
        print("click")
    }

    @objc func longPress(_ sender:Any) {
        guard let gesture = sender as? NSGestureRecognizer else { return }

        switch gesture.state {
        case .ended:
            print("long")
        default:
            print(gesture.state)
        }
    }
}

class MyPressGestureRecognizer: NSPressGestureRecognizer {
    private weak var timer:Timer? = nil
    private var hasBegan = false
    private var hasCancelled = false

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: minimumPressDuration, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            defer {
                timer.invalidate()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.state = .began
                self.hasBegan = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if hasBegan {
            self.state = .ended
            self.hasBegan = false
        }

        super.mouseUp(with: event)
    }

    override func reset() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        super.reset()
    }
}

extension NSGestureRecognizer.State:CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description:String {
        switch self {
        case .possible:
            return "possible"
        case .began:
            return "began"
        case .changed:
            return "changed"
        case .ended:
            return "ended"
        case .cancelled:
            return "cancelled"
        case .failed:
            return "failed"
        @unknown default:
            return "default"
        }
    }
}
```

> However, my customized gesture subclass works exactly the same as the
>   Apple's, which is not working with modal view controllers. So I am
>   daring guessing that Apple also used a `Timer` which causing
>   `NSPressGestureRecognizer` doesn't work in modal view controllers.

## Here is the working code.

```
import Cocoa

class VC: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBrown.cgColor
        let longPress = MyPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

        let click = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(click(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(click)

        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }

    @objc func click(_ sender:Any) {
        print("click")
    }

    @objc func longPress(_ sender:Any) {
        guard let gesture = sender as? NSGestureRecognizer else { return }

        switch gesture.state {
        case .ended:
            print("long")
        default:
            print(gesture.state)
        }
    }
}

class MyPressGestureRecognizer: NSPressGestureRecognizer {
    private var hasBegan = false
    private var hasCancelled = false

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        hasCancelled = false

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(Int(minimumPressDuration * 1000))) {
            if !self.hasCancelled {
                self.state = .began
                self.hasBegan = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if hasBegan {
            self.state = .ended
            self.hasBegan = false
        } else {
            self.hasCancelled = true
        }

        super.mouseUp(with: event)
    }

    override func reset() {
        super.reset()
    }
}

extension NSGestureRecognizer.State:CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description:String {
        switch self {
        case .possible:
            return "possible"
        case .began:
            return "began"
        case .changed:
            return "changed"
        case .ended:
            return "ended"
        case .cancelled:
            return "cancelled"
        case .failed:
            return "failed"
        @unknown default:
            return "default"
        }
    }
}
```

I will mark the other answer as accepted to thank the inspiration to this answer.

## ---------Update with DispatchSourceTimer---------------

```
class MyPressGestureRecognizer: NSPressGestureRecognizer {
    private var hasBegan = false
    private var timer:DispatchSourceTimer? = nil

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
        timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(Int(minimumPressDuration * 1000)))
        timer.setEventHandler {
            self.state = .began
            self.hasBegan = true
        }

        timer.activate()
        self.timer = timer
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if hasBegan {
            self.state = .ended
            self.hasBegan = false
        } else {
            self.timer?.cancel()
        }

        super.mouseUp(with: event)
    }
}
```